# PEAR error "Cannot Find Block 'categories' "

Tags: php, pear

I just new in PEAR programming.
I got a problem when try to passing data from database to html with SIGMA templating. Here the code :

```
$tpl->loadTemplateFile('content_index_form.html');

$csql = "SELECT a.*
            FROM  `dod_cat` a
            LEFT JOIN  `dod_brand` b ON b.sID = a.sID
            WHERE a.status =1
            GROUP BY a.sID";
    $result_category = $mdb2->query($csql);
    if (MDB2::isError($result_category)) {
        die ("Error: ".$result_category->getMessage()." <br>Query:".$csql."<br>");
    }
    $y=0;
    while($row_category = $result_category->fetchRow()){
        $y++;
        $tpl->setVariable(array(
            'cat_id'  => $row_category['sID'],
            'cat_name'  => $row_category['name'],
            'cat_equ'  => $row_category['equ_name'],

        ));
        $tpl->parse('categories');
    }

$tpl->show();
```

Below is template code:

```
<table>
<!-- BEGIN categories -->
<tr>
    <td><a href="{cat_id}">{cat_name}&nbsp;({cat_equ})</a></td>
</tr>
<!-- BEGIN categories -->
</table>
```

And this is the error line **"Cannot find block 'categories'"** show on html page. Is it anybody know what the problem of my code?

Comment: Post the contents of `content_index_form.html`.

Comment: @Sander : i know it's function for parsing the contents to content_index_form.html. But there's an error occured like i said above. Why?

Comment: I don't know why. Probably because there is no `categories` block in your template. Just as the error says. So, post the contents of the `content_index_form.html` template file so we can check.

Comment: i just edited the questions and insert html template code of content_index_form.html. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

```
END categories
```

not two begins.